# how to reduce the width of the colum with line numbers in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

In my (otherwise very pleasant) `Qt Creator`, the column with the line numbers on the left of the text editor takes a lot of precious screen real estate.

Is there a way to reduce the width of that column?

I had no success when searching online or in the documentation.

Thanks!

(Using Qt Creator 3.3.1 on Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column with line numbers is so wide mostly because of its left part which is used for setting breakpoints and bookmarks.
Here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

To make it less wide you can turn off folding markers display or even line numbers display. Relevant setting are 'Display folding markers' and 'Display line numbers' at 'Tools' > 'Options' > 'Text Editor' > 'Display'.

Unfortunately for you there is no option to disable the column left part with breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks! Getting rid of the folding markers display already diminishes the darn column by 25%. I guess this will have to do.